# where is the rest of space?

Tags: 20.04, disk-usage

My computer is having 217GB of storage allocated to it.
[image: size of drive]

But when I scan the root folder it shows 89GB.
[image: size of root]

Does it mean that most of my storage is being used by another directory then root?
Also,  I am continuously getting popups to clear out some space. (I have already tried all the solutions available in other threads and there are no more cache/temp files to delete)

Following is the result of `df -h`

```
(base) sohel@Sohel-pc:/$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  2.1M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/sda5       203G  192G  1.3G 100% /
tmpfs           7.9G  351M  7.5G   5% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       94M   94M     0 100% /snap/core/8935
/dev/loop2      143M  143M     0 100% /snap/code/31
/dev/loop3      143M  143M     0 100% /snap/code/32
/dev/loop1      9.2M  9.2M     0 100% /snap/canonical-livepatch/95
/dev/loop5      243M  243M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/27
/dev/loop4       55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1705
/dev/loop7      127M  127M     0 100% /snap/deja-dup/297
/dev/loop6      127M  127M     0 100% /snap/deja-dup/311
/dev/loop8       55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1754
/dev/loop9      211M  211M     0 100% /snap/eclipse/48
/dev/loop10     291M  291M     0 100% /snap/vlc/1620
/dev/loop11     172M  172M     0 100% /snap/skype/123
/dev/loop12     256M  256M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/33
/dev/loop13     203M  203M     0 100% /snap/vlc/1397
/dev/loop15     148M  148M     0 100% /snap/postman/107
/dev/loop14      94M   94M     0 100% /snap/core/9066
/dev/loop16      50M   50M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/433
/dev/loop17      55M   55M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1502
/dev/loop18     121M  121M     0 100% /snap/docker/423
/dev/loop19      68M   68M     0 100% /snap/jupyter/6
/dev/loop20     175M  175M     0 100% /snap/skype/118
/dev/loop21     148M  148M     0 100% /snap/postman/106
/dev/loop22      63M   63M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
tmpfs           1.6G   56K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sda2       100G   92G  9.0G  92% /media/<username>/3A8EAA898EAA3CEF
/dev/sda3       137G  7.6G  122G   6% /media/<username>/Backup
```

Please help.

Comment: You have given us very little information about the structure of your disk(s). Please edit your question and add the output of `df -h`.

Comment: I have edited the question and added the output. It shows dev/sda5 is using 192G , but /home only occupies 89G.

Comment: Do `sudo du -d 1 -h -x /` to find folders in the root directory. Find out which one is suspiciously large (tens of Gb), let's say `/dir`. Then do `sudo du -d 1 -h -x /dir` and drill down until you find a folder with lots of files or very large files.

Comment: Often space "dissapears" in /var/log. Check if you have any big logfiles, and if, look into them to find the reason.

Answer (score 0):

To find out what space is occupied by some directories, run the next commands in terminal:

```
$ sudo du -h --max-depth=1 /
$ sudo du -h --max-depth=1 /media/<username>/3A8EAA898EAA3CEF/
$ sudo du -h --max-depth=1 /media/<username>/Backup/
```

Then add folder with biggest size to the end of the command:

```
$ sudo du -h --max-depth=1 /home/
```

and so on.